# Rerunning a process/command after an interval after its last completion

Tags: java, shell, ubuntu, cron

I have a java program that I want to run every 2 hours. But I am not sure how long will it take to complete. In some cases, it may take 1 min and in some cases it may take more than 3 hours. Running same command after two hours will result in several instances running in parallel. Hence, I am trying to make it run 2 hours after it finishes. One option is keeping thread.sleep() method in Java. Is there any option I can do in Ubuntu ?

Comment: Can you tell why such a huge difference, and if it's to be expected?

Comment: the program processes data from a changing mysql table. Hence can never be sure if there are 10 rows in it or 10000.

Comment: If you a scheduler (either cron or quartz) it will be harder than it's worth to get the desired behavior. Maybe your simplest option is sleep'ing (even if I find it unrealistc that the same system has such a totally unpredictable load)

Comment: think of a traffic scenario (in night and during office hours). There can many such cases when data fluctuates depending on time.

Comment: Yes, but peeks are consistent between days (or weeks) and you could adjust your scheuld accordingly (for example, execute at 9:00, then at 12:00 then at 18:00, and not execute on sundays - it's just an example, but any scheduler can do this)

Comment: if the data is about website traffic then ? If some celeb tweeted about it, then huge traffic else, less traffic. unpredictable. As I said, there can be several such cases. Accident scenario etc where one can't be sure about data in advance.

Comment: Well, I already told you that a Thread.sleep is enough. Also, I adviced you could use a number of fancy ways to do the same thing when using a scheduler like quartz. Just tried to point out a flaw with your design. You expect your users to wait the background process to finish for a week just because a celebrity tweeted something

Comment: thanks, I am now using Thread.sleep().

Answer (score 0):

The following shell script will only run `my_java_program` if no other instances are running:

```
[ "$(pgrep my_java_program)" ] || my_java_program
```

If your java program is just a bare jar file, say, `mypgm.jar`, then try:

```
[ "$(pgrep -f mypgm.jar)" ] || java -jar mypgm.jar
```

Comment: thanks. is it possible to add a timer to it ? to run it after certain hours?

Comment: @akshayb yes, but your solution of putting it in cron seems easier to me.  Cron would run the line above every two hours while the line above only starts a new java run if the previous run had finished.  Does that work for you?

Comment: I am testing it, not sure how to run .jar from command line ?

Comment: but it doesnt check then (whether its already running or not)

Comment: thanks for update. I tried its working when not using this command in crontab. I tried cron without above, its working means, there is no problem in cron job. What could be reason it doesn't work in crontab ?*/10 * * * * [ "$(pgrep -f myjava.jar)" ] || java -jar /home/JavaPrograms/myjava.jar

Comment: I tried flock :-> */1 * * * *  /usr/bin/flock -w 0 /home/javaProgram/myjava.jar java -jar /home/javaProgram/myjava.jar it  seems working but consuming double memory than usual. Also, there are two pid shown for same command when I do ps aux | grep java

Comment: A common problem with `cron` is that the default `PATH` is quite limited.  Try specifying the full paths to `pgrep` and `java`.  Also, assuming everything is properly set up, `cron` sends all error messages to you by email.  Also, check the log files.  `cron` also leaves messages in the log files (probably `/var/log/messages`).  The log file that they end up in and the level of detail depend on system configuration.

Answer (score 0):

A very basic way to do this could be running your task on any scheduler, like cron/quartz/etc. On each task complete, write/create a file to signify the previous task is complete. On each task start, check for completion. If it has not completed, then skip. Or you could go more complex and write another file to queue the task to run immediately after current task is done. You could apply the same concept to a db table that tracks tasks processed as well.

Of course, you could write your own task managing layer and implement your own scheduling framework hehe